# Jenkins: how to organize bulds in folders for the same repo?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

What I try to achieve.

Current dir structure in a repo:

```
├── accounts
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── eu-west-1
│   │       ├── main.tf
│   ├── prd
│   │   ├── eu-central-1
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── eu-west-1
│   │   │   ├── main.tf
│   └── stg
│       └── eu-west-1
│           ├── main.tf
```

I want to construct a build set like folders in Jenkins UI like this

```
├── MYOWNFOLDER
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── eu-west-1    <- here a builds for this region
│   │ 
│   ├── prd
│   │   ├── eu-central-1 <- here a builds for this region
│   │   ├── eu-west-1    <- here a builds for this region
│   └── stg
│       └── eu-west-1    <- here a builds for this region
```

And I need to have possibility to run builds for a region independently.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @lxop - how to write Jenkinsfile for getting builds per env in separate folders

Comment: to organize your pipelines into folders, you just move them there. If you need to generate a lots of jobs you can use JobDSL to create those jobs automatically. If you want to use the same jenkinsfile for all jobs (if they are similar), you can just have different defaults in the parameters (e.g. for deployment target)